# How to find a "Blank Project" I created

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a project. When start, Google Apps Script asked me "Create script for", and I chose "Blank Project". Ofcouse I renamed it. But now is the problem. It isn't shown in "Recent Project", neither Drive, Sites.

How could I find where it's stored? How could I open it again?

Thanks.

Comment: If you remember a couple of words you typed in that script, the search engine in drive should help you to find it.

Comment: Drive search found nothing. "Create script for" is "Blank Project", none of Script as Web App, Drive, Spreadsheet, Document, Form, Gmail, Calendar, Sites. It's not stored in Drive, I guess so.

Comment: Do you know if it was a standalone script or was it embedded in a document or a site?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an Apps Script bound to a Doc, or Sheet, etc. then you won't see any Project file name in your Drive, you need to open the original file that the script is bound to.